# Use Element.animate() to change background-color

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

Trying to use [`Element.animate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API/Using_the_Web_Animations_API) to change `background-color`, to mimic refresh effect.

**Code:**

```
  const blinkOnPage = (id) => {
    document.getElementById(id).animate(
        [
          {"background-color": '#def', color: '#def'},
        ], {
          easing: 'ease-in-out',
          duration: 200
        });
  }
```

In my test, `color` works, but `background-color` doesn't, how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, just found the solution:

Change `background-color` to `background` works.

```
  const blinkOnPage = (id) => {
    document.getElementById(id).animate(
        [
          {background: '#def', color: '#def'},
        ], {
          easing: 'ease-in-out',
          duration: 100
        });
  }
```

Comment: backgroundColor is what you were looking for.

Comment: `background` and `backgroundColor` aren't exactly equivalent. Changing `background` you'll also update all of `background-XXX` properties, like `-image`, `-position`, `-size` etc.